# изменение названия у кнопки в TableView

Tags: swift, swift3

Добавил класс MenuItemCell, в нем создал @IBOutlet'ы для необходимых кнопок, при инициализации TableView получаю ячейку таким образом:

```
cell = tableActivityTypes.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "activitySubtype")! as! MenuItemCell
```

И далее присваиваю нужной кнопке текст:

```
cell.typeButton.titleLabel?.text = activityTypes[indexPath.row]
```

Но при запуске текст кнопок стандартный "Button". Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проблема решена, виной моя невнимательность - перепутал названия кнопок. @VandrJ спасибо большое! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переносим комментарий в ответ.

Для изменения текста кнопки (`UIButton`) используйте функцию [`setTitle(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle)